# Redux Observable Epic conditional statement using RXJS

Tags: javascript, rxjs, reactive-programming, redux-observable

I am trying to achieve a particular scenario by writing an epic in redux-observable.

**Elements in View**

A dropdown: Dropdown has countries,
A Text box : has the user name field 
A Checkbox : user selection of a persona(similar to admin vs standard)

**Redux State stores the following**

Country Dropdown value
Text Box value and status(disabled or enabled)
Checkbox state

**Assumption**

*If the text box is disabled, it means the text box already has some value.*

I need to call an api(accepts the country and username as input) whenever the user changes the value in the dropdown, or if he un-checks the checkbox(when value is false) or if the text box is disabled.

```
export default (action$: Observable<any>, state$: State$) => {
  const countryValue$ =
    state$.pipe(
      map(o => o.countryCode),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      filter(Boolean),
    );

  const email$ =
    state$.pipe(
      filter(o => o.isTextBoxLocked),
      filter(o => o.isAdmin === false),
      map(o => email),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
    );

  return combineLatest(countryValue$, email$)
    .pipe(map(([country, email]) =>
      actions.fetchData(country, email)));
};
```

The problem is, if the checkbox value is true, still the api call is triggered(because it picks the last value emitted by the email stream). How do I fix this? This is happening because of my usage of combineLatest.

Answer (score 0):

There are four ways to subscribe for multiple streams in rxjs.

CombineLatest, Zip, WithLatestFrom, ForkJoin

All serve its own purpose. For more details,
https://scotch.io/tutorials/rxjs-operators-for-dummies-forkjoin-zip-combinelatest-withlatestfrom

Your problem seems to be different and not based on the operator, the request is getting fired for changes in checkbox though you don't have a subscriber written to it. But its part of the state. You might have to check for filter condition and the key distinctUntilChanged() served its purpose or not.

Comment: Yes, it's not the problem of the operator, it's my inability to device the required flow using the operators.